# What's the difference between np.float64 and tf.float64?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

When working with TensorFlow, and using the file load method from NumPy, it seems to be possible to specify everything as double precision with:

```
np.loadtxt(..., dtype=np.float64)
tf.placeholder(tf.float64...)
tf.Variable(..., dtype=tf.float64...)
```

NumPy and TensorFlow have separate data type values.

If you say `np.loadtxt(..., dtype=tf.float64)` it fails with an error message. Okay, NP was written before TF, so it doesn't understand the TF data type values.

If you say `tf.placeholder(np.float64...)` on the other hand, it seems to work fine. Hmm? Well, TF was written after NP, maybe it's programmed to understand the NP data type values. But why, then, does it have its own separate data type values in the first place instead of just using the NP ones throughout?

What's the difference between the two, as far as TF is concerned? Is it okay to use `np.float64` everywhere, or will that cause problems down the line? (The reason I ask is, I'm thinking of setting a parameter at the start of a program, where you can switch between single and double precision by changing one line, and that would be easier if you can indeed use `np.float64` everywhere.)

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py#L478), it seems that there is a conversion table between np types and tf types (and the other way around). So, if you feed np types, they should be converted into tf types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy's `dtype` and TensorFlow's `DType` are actually different things (Basically, TensorFlow's `DType`s are just values of an internal `enum`, whereas [NumPy's `dtype`s are actual objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html).), therefore NumPy does not understand TensorFlow `DType`s. There are compatible pairs though. You can find out whether your `DType` is NumPy compatible via its property [`is_numpy_compatible`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/DType). TensorFlow accepts NumPy `dtype`s as they sanitize `dtype` parameter inputs in their initialization methods via the [`as_dtype`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/as_dtype) method, that also accepts NumPy `dtype`s, converting them to the proper TensorFlow `DType` value.

So, long story short: You can basically pass `np.float64` and `np.float32` everywhere and TensorFlow will properly handle this.